# Wave function - expected momentum is infinite

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, momentum, wavefunction

I have a wave function, say
$$
\begin{align} 
\Psi(x) = xe^{ikx}
\end{align}
$$

And I want to find the expectation value for momentum, $<p>$

It's not working out to an integral I can evaluate though
$$
\begin{align}
<p> &= \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx \Psi^*(x)(-ih\frac{d}{dx})\Psi(x) \\
& = hk \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx~xe^{-ikx} e^{ikx} (1 + x)  \\
& = hk \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx(x^2 + x)=\infty. 
\end{align}
$$

Does this have a special meaning? Or am I doing something terribly wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s a problem in your wave function: it diverges at infinite far. In real physical system there’s no infinitely big probability density, and the sum of all probabilities is 1. Therefore, the wave function you posted isn’t **normalized**.

Comment: Normalization is done with a constant I think. Since the integral doesn't evaluate, I can't find the constant. Does this mean that it isn't possible to normalize this function?

Comment: @JOE How about free particle eigenstate $e^{ikx}$ with momentum eigenvalue $\hbar k$. But it is not normalizable

Comment: @Alter yep. The function u posted is impossible to normalize cuz it diverges as x increases. Still, you can add a finite interval to x, and do the integral in this specific interval, thus get the value of expected momentum

Comment: @K_inverse I think $e^{ikx}$ is normalized

Comment: @K_inverse u got me in the box therewell idk if it’s normalizable cuz u can add an infinite small constant ahead. Yet anyway it converges at infinite far (integrable), so there’s a corresponding momentum.

Comment: @Alter the plane wave solution $e^{ikx}$ is NOT normalizable.